# Adding data from a DataTable to a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable

After doing some research I found the code below.. I would like to know what I am doing wrong as the code is failing at the line marked with the three stars. I want to copy all the data to a table called api_ReportData on the SQL server.

When trying this, I get the following error: `Cannot find destination table.`

This is my code:

```
DataTable api_ReportData = CreateDataTable();

string sqlConnectionString =
    "Server = 10.72.8.196; Database = datastaoge; User Id = sa; Password = Passw0rd";

// Copy the DataTable to SQL Server
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
    {
        *** s.DestinationTableName = Aapi_ReportData.TableName;

        foreach (var column in Adapi_ReportData.Columns)
            s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

        s.WriteToServer(api_ReportData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've given us the code that you are using, great. Step 1 done. You've told us it breaks 'here', great. Step 2 done. Now step 3 you didn't do. That is, *how does it fail*? What error? Does it fail silently? If it throws an exception, put the entire error & stack trace in your question.

Comment: The `DestinationTableName` property is a string. Try `s.DestinationTableName = "Aapi_ReportData.TableName";`

Comment: I for got that.. the error message is "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: DestinationTableName"

Comment: Have you tried creating the table manually and then running this? If not, try it out and see what happens.

Comment: it may be because of column mismatch in both the table..

Comment: I suggest you change the SA password after this...

Comment: Well, when you debug, does `Aapi_ReportData.TableName` contain the expected table name?

Comment: Now that @ThorstenDittmar mentions it, in your first line you create the datatable - A completely empty, new one. Between that line and the line you marked you don't seem to be editing this datatable at all. How are you planning on setting the destination name equal to a name that simply doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Also, you're using `CreateDataTable()`, are you working in SharePoint or is this a method you wrote yourself? If it's your own creation, could you share this method with us?

Comment: Make sure "Aapi_ReportData.TableName" should represent the `real tablename` that exists in database and columns list should match in both tables. For reference : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net?msg=4570522#xx4570522xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of your error is :

The destination table with name return by Aapi_ReportData.TableName does not exist in your destination database.

if your source and destination table has same schema you do not need to use  s.ColumnMappings.Add